# when try to do bulk upsert in elastic search . iam getting 403 error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

when i try elastic search bulk  upsert , some time iam getting 403 error even for less amount of data . why is that happening

```
AuthorizationException(403, '403 Request throttled due to too many requests /_bulk')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [AWS Elasticsearch documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html):

> If you receive persistent 403 Request throttled due to too many requests errors, consider scaling vertically. Amazon Elasticsearch Service throttles requests if the payload would cause memory usage to exceed the maximum size of the Java heap.

So, you can either send less data or at a lower frequency or add new nodes.

Comment: Thanks although scaling vertically means resizing nodes not adding more

Comment: @StuartClark There's a limit to vertical scaling as the ES heap [shouldn't grow beyond ~32GB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/advanced-configuration.html#setting-jvm-heap-size), hence why horizontal scaling is much more flexible and allows you to grow way further.